# WPF Button click not properly comparing variable to array value

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf

new to WPF so not sure if there is some sort of syntax that I am missing or what.

```
    Course choice;
    int totalCredits = 0;
    int classesRegistered = 0;
    string[] registeredCourses = new string[3];

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (classesRegistered < 3)
        {
            choice = (Course)(this.comboBox.SelectedItem);

            if ((!choice.Equals(registeredCourses[0]))
                && (!choice.Equals(registeredCourses[1]))
                && (!choice.Equals(registeredCourses[2])))
            {
                registeredCourses[classesRegistered] = choice.ToString();
                this.listBox.Items.Add(registeredCourses[classesRegistered]);
                classesRegistered = classesRegistered + 1;
            }

        }
```

}

So I don't want the choice to be added to the listbox if its already registered to one of the array's values.  What is it I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` statement is comparing a `string` to a `Course` object, you may change it to below:

```
if(!registeredCourses.Any(obj=> obj.Equals(choice.ToString())))
```

Comment: Ok thank you for replying.  I see there is also a way to reference all values of an array which I did not know.  So when I use this line of code for my if statement, I get:

 System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: If you are getting the null reference exception in the if statement, it means that either your combo box selected item is null or it can not be cast to a `Course` object. So you may add a null checking before the tostring method

Comment: if(!registeredCourses.Any(obj=> choice!=null && obj.Equals(choice.ToString())))

Comment: Hmmm, I still seem to get the same exception.

Comment: You have to use the visual studio debugger to find out which variable is null

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!